# Cannot run program "make": Launching failed on MinGW-5.1.6 without cygwin in eclipse-SDK-3.2.2-win32

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project helloworld ****

****  WARNING: The "Release" Configuration may not build  ****
****  because it uses the "Cygwin GCC"  ****
****  tool-chain that is unsupported on this system.  ****

****  Attempting to build...  **** 


(Cannot run program "make": Launching failed)
```

I am using `MinGW-5.1.6` (without `Cygwin`) in `Eclipse-SDK-3.2.2-win32`.

Please me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Correct name is `mingw32-make` I think.